# InputField of size that fits the content

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, options

I'd like to have an `InputField` that adjusts its size to the content. I can't make `ImageSize->{All, All}` or anything similar to work.

I was trying to play with `` FEPrivate`StringWidth `` but I am not sure what does it return. It is neither in `px` nor in `em` so the solution below leaves an offset which varies with the string size but with types of characters used aswell:

```
DynamicModule[{x = "test"}
, InputField[Dynamic[x], String
  , FieldSize -> {.5 + 1.5 Dynamic@FEPrivate`StringWidth[x][[1]], 1}
  , ContinuousAction -> True
  , BaseStyle -> 12
  ]
]
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Assuming the font is a fixed width font, can't you just use something like: `.5 + .56 Dynamic@StringLength[x]`, which works well on my MacBook.

Comment: At least for me, your code uses a fixed width font. If I change the base style so that a proportional font is used, e.g., "Times", then your code works fine as well (with a 1. scaling factor instead of 1.5). Could you provide the font that you want to use?

Comment: @CarlWoll It seems I have confused things and your code does fit my needs. Feel free to post it as an answer. Somehow I assumed a string length will be less accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the *{min, max}* syntax for `FieldSize`.

```
InputField[Dynamic[x], String, FieldSize -> {{20, 40}, {1, \[Infinity]}}]
```

The above creates an `InputField` that is initially 20-by-1.  It can expand to fit its contents up to 40 wide and infinitely tall.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, `FieldSize -> {{1, \[Infinity]}, {1, 1}}` is exactly what I need. Somehow I failed to grasp it when I was reading docs. I was trying things like `{1, All}` which work as min/max spec for ImageSize elsewhere.